# Which Lego Set Is This, large white and tan walls, blue base plates?

Tags: set-identification

I picked up a few loose sets. No instructions. Any help appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Taj Mahal, definitely worth your time trying to get it completed/rebuilt ... Many collectors would be very thrilled to find this in a bulk lot, even though the set has recently been re-released.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like the [Taj Mahal (10189)](https://brickset.com/sets/10189-1/Taj-Mahal):

[image: Set photo from Brickset]

The instructions from Lego.com are easily [found on Brickset](https://brickset.com/sets/10189-1/Taj-Mahal) under the instructions tab. It's a beautiful set if you have all of the pieces. Good luck!